# Timing jQuery UI Dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, dialog, popup

I am wondering how can I time how long it takes before the dialog pops up? For example, when you go to a site, i want to set it to 30 seconds before the pop up shows up. Is that possible?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(function(){
                // Dialog           
                if ($.cookie('showDialog') == undefined || $.cookie('showDialog') == null || $.cookie('showDialog') != 'false') {
                $('#dialog').dialog({
                    autoOpen: true,
                    width: 700,
                    modal: true,
                    buttons:{ "No Thanks": function() { $(this).dialog("close"); $.cookie('showDialog', 'false');  } },

                });
                }
                // Dialog Link
                $('#dialog_link').click(function(){
                    $('#dialog').dialog('open');
                    return false;
                });

                //hover states on the static widgets
                $('#dialog_link, ul#icons li').hover(
                    function() { $(this).addClass('ui-state-hover'); }, 
                    function() { $(this).removeClass('ui-state-hover'); }
                );

            });
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout).

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#my-dialog').dialog('open');
},30000);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NMu44/)

Comment: Where would I put that code in my existing one up there? Sorry, I'm not jQuery savvy...